# Axiom of choice in proof of Wigner's theorem?

Tags: proof-explanation, mathematical-physics, axiom-of-choice, quantum-field-theory

In Appendix A of chapter 2 of *The Quantum Theory of Fields*, vol. 1 by Weinberg, he presents a proof of Wigner's theorem: given a symmetry transformation $T$ of rays, one can extend this to a symmetry transformation (which must be either unitary and linear, or antiunitary and antilinear) on the full Hilbert space.

Quoting directly from page 91:

> To start, consider some complete orthonormal set of state-vectors $\Psi_k$ belonging to rays $\mathscr{R}_k$, with ($\Psi_k,\Psi_l) = \delta_{kl}$, and let $\Psi'_k$ be some arbitrary choice of state-vectors belonging to the transformed rays $T\ \mathscr{R}_k$.

My questions:

(1) Am I correct in thinking that Weinberg's proof uses the axiom of choice (to show the existence of the $\Psi'_k$)?

(2) If so, can Weinberg's argument be modified so as not to use the axiom of choice?

Comment: I'm not sure what state vectors are, and what does it mean to belong to a transformed ray.

Comment: It is talking about lifting an (anti)automorphism $T$ of a projectivized Hilbert space, whose points are rays of the Hilbert space, to a linear (anti)automorphism of that Hilbert space.  State vectors are elements of the Hilbert space. @AsafKaragila

Comment: iirc a ray in this case is the set of phases times the vector? Tbh picking 'a basis' probably also invokes the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the full axiom of choice to prove theorems about quantum physics. Dependent choice is enough. However this supposes you only consider separable Hilbert spaces. I don't have Weinberg's book in front of me but I think he is just making that assumption in order to start his proof of Wigner's theorem by invoking the existence of a (countable) orthonormal Hibert space basis $(\Psi_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}_0}$.